# how to make db in laravel using mysql for multiple users, like in my case Admin, Users, Agents, International Agents

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

i want to design a db for my project in laravel but confused how to manage tables. I have four entities Admin, Users, Agents and International Agents. Please help me how i manage my db tables. and if i make single table for multiple users  then how to identify users. 
Note: Each of the mentioned entities are different. Please ask if it not sounds clear. Thanks

Comment: You should have just Users, and assign each one or more Roles. There are various packages for this like https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission, or you can do it yourself.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i want to make it native/custom.

Comment: You should take @ceejayoz advice.  Roles.  From there, you should look into Scopes, because it is very simple to scope your queries automatically based on user-roles.

Comment: @waqarfazal92 It's entirely possible to create a roles system yourself entirely custom. (Kinda wasteful, but entirely possible.) Create a `User` model and a `Role` model. Give `User` a `belongsToMany` relationship on the Roles table via a `role_user` table. Write some logic to check that a user has a particular role.

Comment: thanks alot guys, but problem is that i have two different roles like normal users & agents and both users have different input fields, so how i manage different input fields into single table? i think i should make all the fields that are in both roles( distinct) in a user table, should i do it?  Please any suggestion for this kind of problem?